# Need to clear cells if the edited range is left blank

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp, range

So this formula I'm using for google sheets makes a new date in two boxes to the right of the columns that are edited. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it so that if those cells are left blank after editing, the boxes to the right are removed as well.

I've been googling all over the place about ranges and whatnot.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var Select6 = e.range.getColumn() == 6
    var Select9 = e.range.getColumn() == 9
  if (Select6) {   
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
     e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
  }    
   if (Select9) {              
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());
      e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(new Date());
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Your sheet name goes here.'){return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==6){  
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value.length?new Date():'');
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.value.length?new Date():'');
  }
  if(e.range.columnStart==9){              
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(e.value.length?new Date():'');
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(e.value.length?new Date():'');
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work out for me. The idea is you accidentally filled this column, and need the two cells to the right to clear at the same time as when you delete the entry.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, dude. This was exactly what I was looking for.